# can sombody help me on below script

Tags: powershell, server, active-directory

I am having on script for taking recently joined computers from AD. Its working properly.

But 2 doubts are there..

1. Can we take report for a particular date, If yes please help me with script.
2. Can we take report for particular date and particular time period, If yes please help me with script.

My script is,

$recently = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-30)

Get-ADComputer -Filter 'WhenCreated -ge $recently' -Properties whenCreated | Format-Table Name,whenCreated,distinguishedName -Autosize -Wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the filter like this:

```
-Filter 'WhenCreated -gt $datefrom -and WhenCreated -lt $dateto'
```

and then for a particular date, let's say March 7th:

```
$datefrom = Get-Date '3/7/21'
$dateto = Get-Date '3/8/21'
```

and a particular time period:

```
$datefrom = Get-Date '3/7/21 10:00'
$dateto = Get-Date '3/7/21 11:00'
```